# Wrong URL resulted in pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.

In the PostsController, I have this:

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>array('Reply.post_id'=>$id),'limit' => 1);
$w = $this->paginate($this->Post->Reply); 
$this->set('views', $w);
```

And in the view.ctp, I have this:

```
  <table><tr><td>
        <?php echo $paginator->numbers(); ?>
        <?php
            echo $paginator->prev('Previous', null, null);
            echo $paginator->next(' Next', null, null);?>
     </td></tr></table>
```

And when I pressed the "Next" link, a wrong URL was shown:
http://localhost:8080/post/view/page:2

The correct URL should be
http://localhost:8080/post/view/2/page:2

The ID referring the Post is missing after /post/view/

Could you help me fix the problem please?

I added this to the view.ctp:
$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));

Now the Next and Previous links are corrected, but the
numbers in between the Next and Previous links are still incorrect.

Here is what the Previous and Next links llok like afterwards:
http://localhost:8080/post/view/2/page:2

But the links representing the numbers 1|2|3|4|5 are not changed yet:
http://localhost:8080/post/view/page:2

Any ideas?

Edit reason:
OK,
I altered my code and got a new answer for the question:
Here is the code in my view.ctp file:

```
<?php
    $paginator->options(array('url' => '../view/'.$postid));
    echo $paginator->numbers();
    echo $paginator->prev('Previous', null, null);
    echo $paginator->next(' Next', null, null);    
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near the bottom of this manual page it explains what you must do to have your arguments included in the pagination links.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/166/Pagination-in-Views

The CakePHP manual is your friend!